# Load DLL only when it's needed

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, visual-c++, dll

How can I load a DLL only when it's needed?

I have a program that I set some dependecies (through `Properties > Linker > Input > Additional Dependencias`). But the executable cannot run without this dependecies. How can I create a windows application that only require this DLL when it's needed?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/151kt790.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can load the DLL "manually" using `LoadLibrary` and use `GetProcAddress` to resolve all the symbols. However doing it that way, it's your responsibility to make sure everything is properly loaded and resolved, before any symbols (functions) of the DLL are used.